# Working with two build servers

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We would like to upgrade our clients to VS 2012 without upgrading the TFS server which is TFS 2008. Also, since we have several products, we want to modify the code to be C++11 compatible one product at a time. So the TFS server will have to support and issue builds for both VS 2008 and VS 2012 clients. Does anyone ever configured a TFS 2008 to work with two build servers? Is it even possible?